# Magento 2 - How to use plugin to change product visiblity after saving product from backend?

Tags: magento2, admin, upgrade, visibility

I am new in Magento 2 and I want to change product visibility after saving product from backend using plugin.

For this I have created custom module and plugin, but I am not sure that we can achieve this using of plugin or not? Or Should I go with Observer?

I am trying something like : -

> app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Custom-HelloWorld-product-model" type="Custom\HelloWorld\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
```

> app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/Plugin/ProductPlugin.php

```
namespace Custom\HelloWorld\Plugin;

class ProductPlugin
{    
    public function beforeSetVisiblity(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $visiblity)
    {
        ....
    } 
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can go with plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I also have to update DB value as well. Can you please give me any doc links so I can get more information and implement this in our module.

Comment: Sure, you can learn more from here : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use plugin not observer, there is something need to understand that where to use plugin and where to use observers :

**Use Plugins :**
If you are going to change input, output ( i.e set / save data ) of some function or changing flow of request then should use plugin.

**User Observer :**
If you are not going to change the flow of request and intended to perform some other action on event then use Observer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. I have to update DB value as well. Can you please give me any doc links so I can get more information and implement this in our module.